# Webjars not reachable on Weblogic Server

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, gradle, weblogic12c, webjars

What should I do to be able to access the Webjars from Angular application on Weblogic Server?

I've received basic temporary project, which is running on Tomcat, but on Weblogic it's not working properly. After few modifications, I was able to deploy the application, but I'm not able to run it properly. The webjars are still not visible. What's more, I also found that for Weblogic 12C, I should use this dependency in `Gradle`:

```
compile 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-weblogic:0.9'
```

but after that, I'm not able to deploy the application because I'm receiving an error "URI is not hierarchical". Without this dependency, I'm able to deploy the application and see the `index.html`, but it points to other `js` file like this:

```
<script data-main="js/configImport" src="webjars/requirejs/require.min.js"></script>
```

which contains something like this:

```
require.config({

    map: {
        '*': {
            'css': 'webjars/require-css/css'
        }
    },

    paths: {
        'angular': 'webjars/angularjs/angular.min',
        'myApp': 'js/app',
        'cssCore': 'js/cssCore'
    },

    shim: {
        'angular': {exports: 'angular'},
    },

    baseUrl: '.'
});

require(['angular', 'myApp', 'cssCore', 'js/controllers/MainCtrl'], function (angular) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

<strike>I also tried to add this line to `servlet.xml` file:</strike>

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

but with no success.

All the webjars are added by `Gradle` as dependencies. `spring-boot` and `webjars-locator` are at compile level, the rest like `angularjs` at runtime level.

What am I missing? What should I do in this case to make it work?

**UPDATE :**

I'm adding the [stack trace](https://pastebin.com/EpWnTJga) from the deployment with `webjars-locator-weblogic`. The question is if do I need to put both: `webjars-locator` and `webjars-locator-weblogic` or only weblogic version? 
I tried with both and in both cases I'm getting the same error. I tried to solve this problem by adding `WebConfig` class like its done [here](https://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc) and even adding the code in `Main` class like it's done under the same link but at the topic `Enhanced support for RequireJS`. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I still can't access the webjars.

Comment: Why the xml file? Looks like the application deployed to tomcat is started different then the one on weblogic leading to different configurations.

Comment: @M.Deinum original application works on Tomcat. I provided few changes in order to deploy it on Weblogic. I've added `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` to `web.xml` in order to access resources, which for some reasons didn't work without it. So it also required the `servlet.xml` file. Originally it was just empty file with the `<beans>`, but I've found this `<mvc:resouces>` so I thought that it should be added there in order to make it work. The question is what I should do to run this properly on Weblogic? I don't care about Tomcat...

Comment: You shouldn't need/have an `xml` file with Spring Boot... So I would revert those changes and do as mentioned in the spring boot reference guide here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-weblogic

Comment: Ok right, but it doesn't change anything... Still the same problems that webjars are not reachable.

Comment: Did you add the `webjars-locator-weblogic` dependency?

Comment: Did you read my whole post...? Here is this part from post: "What's more, I also found that for Weblogic 12C, I should use this dependency in Gradle:
`compile 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-weblogic:0.9'`
but after that, I'm not able to deploy the application because I'm receiving an error `"URI is not hierarchical"`.

Comment: Yes I did read that and still wondered if you added that... For Weblogic that is needed to resolve the resources, else it will not work (due to resource loading differences on WebLogic).

Comment: I've added, but after that I'm not able to deploy the application, because I'm receiving the error given in post/comment.... So this dependency is not really helpful...

Comment: You must be using an URL somewhere that doesn't satisfy the web logic resolver. Never used that thing but if it was something nicely written it should give you the path that it is failing on.

Comment: I don't have the full URLs or something like this... In Java mock there are only request mappings and `api.json` with parts of URL's, which seems to be pointing or something to those request mappings...

Comment: Do you only get an error or do you get a stack trace?

Comment: Take a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already got it working, but what works for me with weblogic 12.2.1.3 is:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

All js/css are then resolved correctly. 
Example: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/app-name/webjars/angular/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>`

On a side not, i am using "standard" spring, not boot. Shouldn't make any difference though. Webjars are packed inside the war (in WEB-INF\lib) while the remaining dependencies (spring, aspectj, other application modules, etc.) are packed inside the ear package.
The build comes down to a ear package containing:

- all the project dependencies (in /lib folder)
- war file containing just the webapp with the webjars in (WEB-INF\lib)

What i can't get to work with weblogic is the version agnostic locator. Have tried with both standard webjars-locator and webjars-locator-weblogic with no luck.

[EDIT]
On a side note, i did get that same error you got (URI not hierarchical) when, by mistake, i placed the webjar dependencies on the ear module instead of the war one. 
After placing them in the war, i found out that weblogic is rather "sensitive" regarding the servlet mappings. I had the standard servlet mapping pattern to root (like i usually have on other servers) and that was somehow messing with the remaining mappings (webjars included). In the end i had to specify a url pattern other then to be handled by Spring alone.